# My dependency injection with Spring is not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection

Spring is not doing dependency injection on objects annotated with `@Autowired`.
When the request is made to the endpoint, the following error appears:
`java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.myproject.entity.service.IMyEntityService.getAllMyEntities()" because "this.myEntityService" is null`

**- MyEntityController:** This class has a few methods, but all of them have the same error, so I left only this one as an example.

---

```java
package com.myproject.api.controller;

import com.myproject.entity.model.MyEntity;
import com.myproject.entity.service.IMyEntityService;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
 
import java.util.List;
 
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class MyEntityController {

  @Autowired
  IMyEntityService myEntityService;

  @GetMapping("/my-entities")
  @CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
  @ResponseBody
  public List<MyEntity> getAllMyEntities(){

  List<MyEntity> myEntities = myEntityService.listAllMyEntities();
      return myEntities;
  }

}
```

**- MyEntityService:** Even if I make a `MyEntityService` instance manually in the Controller, `MyEntityRepository` also shows the dependency injection error, which shows that Spring is not injecting into any of my interfaces.

```java
@Service
public class MyEntityService implements IMyEntityService {

    @Autowired
    MyEntityRepository myEntityRepository ;

    @Override
    public List<MyEntityService > listAllMyEntities() {
        return this.myEntityRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

**-MyEntityRepository:**

```java
@Repository
public interface MyEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<MyEntity, Long> {
}
```

I have tried several things to solve this, like creating a static method to configure Spring and forcing Spring to scan. I tried using ComponentScan and putting the path of the packages, and I tried putting settings on application.proprieties, but none of it worked.

Comment: `@Service` is imported from the correct package ?

Comment: @PeterMmm yes, I imported from import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

Comment: Are you doing right package scan on startup?

Comment: try constructor injection and see what happens? remove autowired and: public MyEntityController(IMyEntityService service){ this.myEntityService=service;}

Comment: @David This works in the Service, but I get an error in the Repository, since I can't do this injection in the constructor because Repository is an interface.

Comment: how does your public static void main look? did you mess with configuration somewhere? looks like spring is confused, because if constructor injection worked, your autowired should have worked as well...

Comment: @David this is my Public Static Void Main:

'@'SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }

}

Comment: No idea whats wrong tbh, but @SpringBootApplication annotation is good enough to make spring autoscan and autowire. maybe try to undo all those attempts to force ComponentScan etc,..  just start new project, create a system.out.println interface/service and get them to autowire and work first?

Comment: Maybe you can share the package structure of your application. The springboot auto scan will pick beans in the same package + internal packages from your `MyApplication` class, so checking that Service and Repository are in the proper hierarchy is worth a shot

Answer (score 0):

There could be several reasons for potential bugs here, but overall, it's clear that there is a problem caused by not doing proper dependency injection. You can make edits such as:

```
package com.myproject.api.controller;

import com.myproject.entity.model.MyEntity;
import com.myproject.entity.service.IMyEntityService;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

import java.util.List;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class MyEntityController {

    private final IMyEntityService myEntityService;

    @Autowired
    public MyEntityController(IMyEntityService myEntityService) {
        this.myEntityService = myEntityService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/my-entities")
    @CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
    @ResponseBody
    public List<MyEntity> getAllMyEntities(){
        List<MyEntity> myEntities = myEntityService.listAllMyEntities();
        return myEntities;
    }

}
```

-MyEntityService:

```
@Service
public class MyEntityService implements IMyEntityService {

  private final MyEntityRepository myEntityRepository;

  @Autowired
  public MyEntityService(MyEntityRepository myEntityRepository) {
      this.myEntityRepository = myEntityRepository;
  }

  @Override
  public List<MyEntity> listAllMyEntities() {
      return this.myEntityRepository.findAll();
  }
}
```

=MyEntityRepository:

```
@Repository
public interface MyEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<MyEntity, Long> {
}
```

The most important point to note here is that you make sure that the dependencies are properly injected. This is done in MyEntityController, making sure you define an appropriate constructor and place @Autowired in the constructor. Similarly, in MyEntityService, define the appropriate constructor and insert @Autowired accordingly.

Comment: Can you please explain why do you put Autowired annotation on constructor injection?

Comment: When using constructor injection, you can use the @Autowired annotation on the constructor to tell Spring to automatically inject the required dependencies. This is known as "constructor-based dependency injection".

Comment: In Spring, there are three types of dependency injection: constructor injection, setter injection, and field injection.

Constructor injection is considered to be the most recommended way to inject dependencies. The reason for this is that constructor injection ensures that all the required dependencies are provided when an object is instantiated. It makes the object's state immutable after construction, which can help to prevent subtle bugs and ensure thread-safety.

Comment: The constructor injection works also without the Autowired annotation. What is the benefit of adding it?

Comment: I wont torture you anymore:  https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#beans-constructor-injection

Comment: Adding the @Autowired annotation in the constructor injection is not mandatory, but it helps to improve the code's readability and maintainability.

Comment: Firstly, it makes the dependency injection more explicit and easier to understand for other developers who might read the code. When they see the @Autowired annotation, they can quickly tell that this is an injection point, and they can easily trace the dependencies to see how the code works.

Comment: Secondly, it helps to prevent errors caused by not injecting dependencies correctly. If you forget to inject a dependency or if you inject the wrong type of dependency, Spring will throw an error at runtime. However, if you use the @Autowired annotation, Spring will detect any missing or incorrect dependencies during the application context initialization phase, and it will fail fast, giving you an opportunity to fix the issue before your code is deployed.

Comment: Finally, the @Autowired annotation allows you to use constructor injection even when you have multiple constructors in your class.

Comment: Nevertheless, in your answer you are adding something which is not mandatory, is not improving on functionality, is an extra line of code and is essentially a developers choice. At the same time you are claiming it is the necessary part of proper way to inject dependency. I personally find your answer misleading.

Comment: *The most important point to note here is that you make sure that the dependencies are properly injected. This is done in MyEntityController, making sure you define an appropriate constructor and place Autowired in the constructor. Similarly, in MyEntityService, define the appropriate constructor and insert Autowired accordingly.*    looks pretty mandatory to me...

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine, so my suggestions will be both symantic and related to repackaging.

Try the following:

1. You can remove the @Repository annotation, extending JpaRepository is suffient.
2. Delete the controller & service & repository packages and recreate them under
   the main package.
   com.myproject.api